# ICEPDF Printing Problem

Tags: java, pdf, printing, icepdf

I am using ICEPDF to show and print a PDF doc within my Java Application.

I get the following exception:

```
org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Catalog <clinit>
INFO: ICEsoft ICEpdf Core 4.1.4 
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.PrintHelper.getSetupDialog(PrintHelper.java:526)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.PrintHelper.setupPrintService(PrintHelper.java:199)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController.initialisePrinting(SwingController.java:2590)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController.access$400(SwingController.java:102)
    at org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController$3.run(SwingController.java:2548)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

The code I am using is:

```
public class ViewerComponentExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get a file from the command line to open
        String filePath = "boll.pdf";

        // build a component controller
        SwingController controller = new SwingController();

        SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

        JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

        // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
        controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                        controller.getDocumentViewController()));

        JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
        applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

        // Now that the GUI is all in place, we can try openning a PDF
        controller.openDocument(filePath);

        // show the component
        applicationFrame.pack();
        applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The above shows the viewer fine and it allows all operations apart from printing! (see exception above).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the icepdf help forums? They are usually pretty good at answering questions.

Comment: I sorted it. Problem was that my printer wasn't setup as a default printer! 
There is no handling of "no default printer", if it is not there (even if you have a printer) icepdf throws an exception.

Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, this exception appears when no printer is available on you OS.
Here is the icepdf source code:

```
return ServiceUI.printDialog(graphicsConfiguration,
    point.x,
    point.y,
    services, services[0],
    DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE,
    printRequestAttributeSet);
```

"services" is defined like this:

```
private PrintService[] lookForPrintServices() {
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
        DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);
    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    if (defaultService != null && services.length &gt; 1) {
        PrintService printService;
        for (int i = 1, max = services.length; i &lt; max; i++) {
            printService = services[i];
            if (printService.equals(defaultService)) {
                PrintService tmp = services[0];
                services[0] = defaultService;
                services[i] = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return services;
}
```

If no services match, the "services" array is zero-length:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html#lookupPrintServices(javax.print.DocFlavor, javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet)

Maybe a solution would be to create a "/dev/null" printer. I don't know how if this is easy to do...